# Circuit probability question regarding sum of a random number of independent random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, geometric-probability

Suppose we have n circuits that operate in a home. Each one will live according to an exponential random variable with rate λ. If X denotes the time at which a circuit ﬁrst dies (i.e. the ﬁrst circuit to die out of the n circuits), what is the PDF of X? Is this a “special” random variable? If so, give the corresponding parameter.

Not really sure how to start on this. I thought that I should find the transform of X and then get the PDF out of that but I'm not really sure how exactly to approach this. Any tips will help, thanks.

Comment: The idea is to consider the probability $P(X > r)$, and the cumulative function can be deduced from it as $1 - P(X > r)$. Take a look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Distribution_of_the_minimum_of_exponential_random_variables) on the subject.

Comment: Hint: What is the probability that each of the circuits lasts at least $x$ minutes? Now, what is the probability that one lasts less than $x$ and the rest more than $x$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$ be the lengths of life of the $n$ circuits, assumed independent. Let $X=\min(X_1,\dots,X_n)$. We want the distribution of $X$.

We find the cumulative distribution function $F_X(x)$ of $X$. Obviously $F_X(x)=0$ if $x\le 0$. So from now on assume that $x\gt 0$.

The probability that $X$ is $\gt x$ is the probability that all the $X_i$ are greater than $x$. If the $X_i$ are exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda$, then $\Pr(X_i\gt x)=e^{-\lambda x}$. So by independence the probability that all the $X_i$ are $\gt x$ is $(e^{-\lambda x})^n$, that is, $e^{-n\lambda x}$.

It follows that $\Pr(X\le x)=1-e^{-n\lambda x}$. Thus $X$ has exponential distribution with parameter $n\lambda$. If you want the density function of $X$, calculate $F_X'(x)$.